# Is there any tool to convert from XAML to C# (code behind)?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am looking for an easy way to convert some XAML animation to C# code.  Is there any tool available to do that?

Thanks!

Wally

This is the code I am trying to convert:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
  <Rotation3DAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
      Storyboard.TargetName="DefaultGroup"
      Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Visual3D.Transform).(Transform3DGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform3D.Rotation)">
    <SplineRotation3DKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:04.0200000">
      <SplineRotation3DKeyFrame.Value>
        <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="144.99999999999997" Axis="1,0,0"/>
      </SplineRotation3DKeyFrame.Value>
    </SplineRotation3DKeyFrame>
  </Rotation3DAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the same code in c#:

```
Storyboard storyboard3 = new Storyboard();

storyboard3.AutoReverse = false;
Rotation3DAnimationUsingKeyFrames r3d = new Rotation3DAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
r3d.BeginTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
r3d.Duration = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,1,0);

r3d.KeyFrames.Add(new SplineRotation3DKeyFrame(new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(1,0,0),1)));
r3d.KeyFrames.Add(new SplineRotation3DKeyFrame(new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(1, 0, 0), 37)));
r3d.Name = "r3d";

Storyboard.SetTargetName(r3d, "DefaultGroup");
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(r3d, new PropertyPath("(Visual3D.Transform).(Transform3DGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform3D.Rotation)")); 

storyboard3.Children.Add(r3d);
this.BeginStoryboard(storyboard3);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use XamlReader.Load("") to parse it. Hope it helps :)

Edit:

```
StoryBoard myStoryBoard = (StoryBoard)XamlReader.Load("code");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , it works but I am trying to modify some values at runtime and I think I need direct access to the variables involved in the animation, I will test it...

Comment: You should be able to access the storyboards content through the children collection (myStoryBoard.Children[0] should be your rotation).

You could also try to create it completely in codebehind, see: http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/f442644f-a6e1-47f1-8d6f-f65ab3949eee

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to convert the XAML to procedural code? If I read one of your comments correctly it's because you need to change values at runtime.  If this is the case, [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612.aspx) may be better.  Could you describe what you're trying to do with the C# that you can't do with XAML?